# Sort xml in php, but keep as xml object

Tags: php, arrays, xml, sorting

I have a simplexml object in php, and I was asked to sort the xml before exporting it.
The xml was loaded from an external source:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($DOM); 
return($xml->asXml());
```

The xml export right now looks like this:

```
<item>
<rec-key>101010</rec-key>
<barcode>0001</barcode>
<sub-library>Lib1</sub-library>
<collection>3</collection>
<item-status>51</item-status>
<call-no-1>K-05200</call-no-1>
<description>1996 VOL.1</description>
<chronological-i>1996</chronological-i>
<enumeration-a>1</enumeration-a>
</item>
```

What I need is to sort the xml by the sub-library field, then by the description field.
I tried several different solutions so far (including XSL formatting, json, etc.), based on other questions in this site, but nothing seems to have worked. Note that I attempted many edits to the code, so it might look slightly different than it does in the original answers:

```
// Sort by location and call-number
            //$array=json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($xml)),1);
//osort($array, array('sub-library' => SORT_ASC, 'description' => SORT_ASC));

//Load sorting XSL
$xsl = new DOMDocument();
$xsl->load("SortXsl.xsl");

//Apply sorting XSL
$sortxml = new DOMDocument();
$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStylesheet($xsl);
$sortxml = $proc->transformToDoc($xml);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$items = iterator_to_array($doc->getElementsByTagName('item'));
usort($items, 
function($a, $b) { 
    $aFoo = (int)$a->getElementsByTagName('sub-library')[0]->textContent;
    $bFoo = (int)$b->getElementsByTagName('sub-library')[0]->textContent;
    $result = $aFoo - $bFoo;
    if ($result == 0) {
        $aBar = $a->getElementsByTagName('description')[0]->textContent;
        $bBar = $b->getElementsByTagName('description')[0]->textContent;
        return strcmp($aBar, $bBar);
    }
    else {
        return $result;
    }
});

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $item->parentNode->appendChild($item);
}

$sortable = array();
foreach($xml->result as $node) {
    $sortable[] = $node;
}

function sortarray($a, $b)
{
    // sort by sub-library
    $retval = strnatcmp($a->sub-library, $b->sub-library);
    // if identical, sort by description
    if(!$retval) $retval = strnatcmp($a->description, $b->description);
    return $retval;
}

// sort alphabetically by library and description
usort($sortable, __NAMESPACE__ . '\sortarray');
$xml2=new SimpleXMLElement('<items/>');
array_walk_recursive($sortable, array ($xml2, 'addChild'));


$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
echo ($array);
$sort = array();
foreach($array as $k=>$v) {
    $sort['sub-library'][$k] = $v['sub-library'];
    $sort['description'][$k] = $v['description'];
}
array_multisort($sort['sub-library'], SORT_ASC, $sort['description'], SORT_DESC,$mylist);
$xml2 = new SimpleXMLElement('<item/>');
$xml2->loadXML($sort);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'sub-library'), SORT_ASC,
        array_column($array, 'title'), SORT_DESC,
        $array);
$xml2 = new SimpleXMLElement('<item/>');
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $xml2->addChild($key, $value);
}
```

Are there any other ways? Or what am I doing wrong with the codes I already tried?

Comment: Why the code is all commented out? Hard to say what is in use and what not.

Comment: Nothing is in use because nothing worked :( it is commented out because I commented out each attempt after it failed.

Comment: I think you should aim to order the elements at array level first and then take care of the XML output. Divide and conquer :-)

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I don't mind that, but then how do I convert the array to xml again? Several of my solutions went that route but I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a function of the DOM extension - `DOMXpath:evaluate()`. It allows you to use Xpath expressions to fetch nodes or values from a DOM Node Tree, just like in XSLT.

```
$document = new \DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new \DOMXpath($document);

$items = iterator_to_array($xpath->evaluate('/items/item'));
usort(
  $items,
  function(\DOMElement $a, \DOMElement $b) use ($xpath) {
    $i = strnatcmp(
      $xpath->evaluate('string(sub-library)', $a),
      $xpath->evaluate('string(sub-library)', $b)
    );
    if ($i === 0) {
      return strnatcmp(
        $xpath->evaluate('string(description)', $a),
        $xpath->evaluate('string(description)', $b)
      ); 
    }
    return $i;
  }
);

foreach ($items as $item) {
  echo $xpath->evaluate('string(rec-key)', $item), ",\n";
}
```

`$items = iterator_to_array($xpath->evaluate('/items/item'));` fetches all the item nodes as node list. You approach with `iterator_to_array()` and `usort()` is a good one, but the compare function can be simplified a lot.

`$xpath->evaluate('string(sub-library)', $a)` fetches the first `sub-library` element node as a string. `$a` is the context node for the expression.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.
Why did you put \ before the DOMXpath, DOMDocument and DOMElement? Is it by design?

Also - at the end, you use echo to reconstruct the file after sorting, but how do I create an xml out of it? Is it supposed to be instead of the return function?

Thank you

Comment: Did you happen to see my question in the comment?

Comment: The backslash means root PHP namespace. To create  new XML document, create it, create/append the root nodes/structure, import append the sorted nodes, save the new document - it is a different task/question.

Comment: Thank you. It's actually not a different question, as I originally asked right in the title how do I keep the xml structure I started with, just sorted, because the xml return is going as an input to another function and must remain as it was.